# Spring Integration Tests

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to create simple test for checking that error channel gets the message from flow channel

```
@Bean(START_PROCESSING_CHANNEL)
MessageChannel processingStart() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean(CUSTOM_ERROR_CHANNEL)
MessageChannel channelError() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Code works fine, but have some problems with tests creation - I send message to processingStart channel, interceptor works fine, but I get payload with headers from buildErrorStartMessage() or test fails when I add *

```
    when(processor.registerNewEntity(any(), any())).thenReturn(buildEntityErrorMessage());
    when(processor.transformEntity(any(), any())).thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()); (*)
    startChannel.addInterceptor(new WireTap(errorChannel));
    startChannel.send(buildErrorStartMessage());
    verify(errorHandler,times(1)).processException(messageArgumentCaptor.capture());
```

I think thats correct, but how can I catch an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is not clear, the `WireTap` just emits the message sent to the channel this interceptor has been added.

If that is really enough for your, then your `errorHandler` has to be subscribed to your `errorChannel`. But again: this is not an error - just sent message interception and producing it to that `errorChannel`.

See more info in Spring Integration docs about testing: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing

Comment: yes, for error flow I have this     `@Bean
    IntegrationFlow errorFlow(ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(channelError())
            .handle(message -> errorHandler.processException(message)).get();
    }`

Comment: OK. How do you mock that `errorHandler`?

Comment: yes, for error flow I have handler, code works fine and firstly I just directly send message to ErrorChannel and verify that errorhandler is called, but not sure thats good test))I'm very new in Spring integration, so I decide to try send message to flowchannel and want to receive it in errorchannel.

Comment: like this `@Bean
        ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
            return mock(ErrorHandler.class);
        }`

Comment: Looks good. Not sure what is the problem. Maybe you can show more code where does it fail? Perhaps you try to assert all the headers where they can be modified from channel to channel since the message is an immutable object?

Comment: how can I emulate this error interception it test? `@Bean     IntegrationFlow errorFlow(ErrorHandler errorHandler) {         return IntegrationFlows.from(channelError())             .handle(message -> errorHandler.processException(message)).get();     }`

Comment: Since your `ErrorHandler` is mocked, I don't see a problem with that your `verify()` in the end of your code snippet. According the info you provide for us it looks like everything is done in the same thread, so your `verify()` is legit to be performed just after that `send()`.

Comment: yes, verify() works, but Im not sure that my test is good enough. I want to: 1.send message to startChannel; 2. throw error in any handle method in startChannel; 3. catch error in errorHandler. Code works in this way, but its difficult to do the same in test(( thanks anyway @Artem Bilan

Comment: If your flow is fully direct, everything happens on the same thread. So, throwing an exception somewhere downstream will just bubble it up to the caller. So, plain `try..catch()` for your `startChannel.send()` is enough to handle it. Your `ErrorHandler` is not going to work in this case, just because there is no an sync hand off for any existing error handling mechanism in Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling